# TypeError $(...) is not a function when using a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I got one for the Jquery experts.

I downloaded a simple jquery plugin to convert from Table to CSV.

Here is the source code... http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.js

Now, I created a local jscript file. jquery.Table2CSV.js. I added to my page right after my jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/libs/jquery-1.6.3.min.js")'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.Table2CSV.js")'></script>
```

It's loading correct (200 OK) according to Firebug.

In one of my views, i have the following code...

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#exportToCSV").click(function (event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            alert('button clicked!');
            $('#reportDataTable').table2CSV();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The trigger fires the click event, no problem, but i get the following error.

TypeError: $(...).table2CSV is not a function

(?)(event=Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=88685109, more...})summary (line 109)
add(c=Object { originalEvent=Event click, type="click", timeStamp=88685109, more...})asset....zogAQAA (line 3)
add(a=click clientX=849, clientY=231)asset....zogAQAA (line 3)
[Break On This Error]

$('#reportDataTable').table2CSV();

I tried to find something meaningful here but no solution so far.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is the source code for the plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.table2CSV = function(options) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        separator: ',',
        header: [],
        delivery: 'popup' // popup, value
    },
    options);

    var csvData = [];
    var headerArr = [];
    var el = this;

    //header
    var numCols = options.header.length;
    var tmpRow = []; // construct header avalible array

    if (numCols > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
            tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData(options.header[i]);
        }
    } else {
        $(el).filter(':visible').find('th').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
        });
    }

    row2CSV(tmpRow);

    // actual data
    $(el).find('tr').each(function() {
        var tmpRow = [];
        $(this).filter(':visible').find('td').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') tmpRow[tmpRow.length] = formatData($(this).html());
        });
        row2CSV(tmpRow);
    });
    if (options.delivery == 'popup') {
        var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
        return popup(mydata);
    } else {
        var mydata = csvData.join('\n');
        return mydata;
    }

    function row2CSV(tmpRow) {
        var tmp = tmpRow.join('') // to remove any blank rows
        // alert(tmp);
        if (tmpRow.length > 0 && tmp != '') {
            var mystr = tmpRow.join(options.separator);
            csvData[csvData.length] = mystr;
        }
    }
    function formatData(input) {
        // replace " with â€œ
        var regexp = new RegExp(/["]/g);
        var output = input.replace(regexp, "â€œ");
        //HTML
        var regexp = new RegExp(/\<[^\<]+\>/g);
        var output = output.replace(regexp, "");
        if (output == "") return '';
        return '"' + output + '"';
    }
    function popup(data) {
        var generator = window.open('', 'csv', 'height=400,width=600');
        generator.document.write('<html><head><title>CSV</title>');
        generator.document.write('</head><body >');
        generator.document.write('<textArea cols=70 rows=15 wrap="off" >');
        generator.document.write(data);
        generator.document.write('</textArea>');
        generator.document.write('</body></html>');
        generator.document.close();
        return true;
    }
};
```

Ok. New EDIT
At the end of my scripts, I had this from Mr. Telerik...

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().DefaultGroup(group => group.Combined(true).Compress(true)))
```

I removed it and it worked just fine. One little problem thou. Now my jqueries from Telerik don't work.... I am doing some research in the meantime on how to make this guy to coexist with my jqueries.

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that `$` has been overridden by either another copy of jQuery, or another library/function entirely

Comment: Ok... Thanks. But i don't really know how to fix this. Do you know?

Comment: Are you sure you have the right version of Jquery?

Comment: Yeah, to fix it don't include more than one copy of jQuery. I can't tell where you've gone wrong, i'd have to follow your url but i don't follow external url's from here.

Comment: The right JQuery version? I am totally lost on that one. I know I have other plugins (tips, context menu, etc) and they all working fine.

Comment: I just edited it my post. I added the plugin source code.

Comment: If another library is overriding the $ for jQuery - have you tried encapsulating your jQuery code in anonymous function like `;(function($){})(jQuery);`  then call `$.noConflict` before you use the other library that uses $ ?

Comment: It's Telerik screwing up. Look at my last Edit. Now i have to figure out how to make them coexist together.....

Answer (score -1):

Solved.... Here is the solution.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-doesn-t-let-me-work-with-jquery-ui.aspx

I hope it helps people in the future.

Basically, seems like this telerik registration of their own jquery files also adds jquery (double registration).

Thank you