# jQuery library "not a function" when called in a click event

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, click, typeerror

I'm trying to apply the jQuery Text Editor library to a P tag which is populated by an Ajax call, inside a modal. This is part of a somewhat old and Ajax heavy site with many different jQuery versions being loaded, but running

```
$.fn.jQuery
```

in the JS console at any point returns "2.1.4".

I know the libraries do load to the page, as applying ".jqte()" to an existing/"static" element on the page transforms it as intended. This is before the modal is loaded/visible in the flow of the program.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".odd").jqte(); 
});
```

The above snippet does turn all ".odd" elements into little text editors.

```
$("#showScraper").click(function(){
    $(".editor").jqte();
});
```

The above is what is causing me pain.

I'm having a hard time discerning why the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jqte is not a function
```

appears only when

```
$(".myClass").anyLibrary();
```

is called inside my click event. This also applies to IDs.

Any idea what could cause this? jQuery version conflict?
[This question seems similar, and suggests that it could be a version conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709895/typeerror-is-not-a-function-when-using-a-jquery-plugin/)

Is it possible that somehow the html  imports aren't read when the Ajax call is done? Or do I not understand scope?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Some code:

PHP generating the HTML and content to be placed inside the modal:

```
echo '<div id="scrapedText"><p class="editor" name="text1">';
            foreach ($matchContent['about']['p'] as $key => $value) {
                echo $value , "<br /><br />";
            }
echo '</p></div><br/>';
```

The link that opens the modal:

```
$button = '<p><a href="/my/ajax/path" id="showScraper" rel="modal:open">Show me the stuff</a></p>';
```

My imports:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jquery.modal.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.modal.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/jQuery-TE_v.1.4.0/jquery-te-1.4.0.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jQuery-TE_v.1.4.0/jquery-te-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *"jQuery version conflict?"* Yes. You're loading the plugin for one instance of jQuery, but not for the other(s), and not for the version being used by the code that fails. I don't see how this isn't a duplicate of the one you linked.

Comment: *"This is part of a somewhat old and Ajax heavy site with many different jQuery versions being loaded..."* Stop what you're doing and *fix that*. Load a single copy of jQuery. Loading multiple copies bloats your page, increases load time, and leads to hassles like the one you're running into.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Clean-up is certainly something I'm interested in doing. Could you elaborate a bit on your first comment? I feel like I'm missing the crux of it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said your site is loading jQuery more than once (multiple different versions). That's not shown in the list of `script` tags you included in the question, but I assume it is actually true.

That means you're only adding the plugin to the version of jQuery that controlled the `jQuery` variable as of when you loaded the plugin. So for instance:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
// Note -------------------^
    $(".selector1").click(function() {
        $(this).niftyPlugin();
    });
});
</script>
<!-- ... -->
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="nifty-plugin.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
// Note -------------------^
    $(".selector2").click(function() {
        $(this).niftyPlugin();
    });
});
</script>
```

In the code above, clicks on `.selector1` element will throw an error because they're using jQuery 1.7.2 and `niftyPlugin` isn't installed on your copy of jQuery 1.7.2. Clicks on `.selector2` will work, because the plugin is installed on the other copy of jQuery, 2.1.4. When the second copy was loaded, both `$` and `jQuery` were updated to point to *it*; but the code inside the `ready` callback is using the argument (`$`) it receives, which is a reference to the jQuery object that is making that `ready` call (in the first case, v1.7.2; in the second case, v2.1.4).

The best answer to making this work is not to use multiple copies of jQuery.

The second-best answer is to always be aware of which version of jQuery a given bit of code is using as `$` or `jQuery`.

Comment: Thanks much. I trust this to be the info I need and I'll keep on keeping on. Still trying to understand this system I've been dropped into!